# Does Deuteronomy 24:16 contradict what happened to King David’s son?

Tags: talmud-gemara, king-david

Deuteronomy 24:16 says a child will not be punished for the sins of the father and vice versa. Then how is it the child of David and Bathsheba be put to death? What is the reason for this according to the Talmud?

Comment: Deuteronomy is talking about the justice that humans carry out. (In fact, II Kings actually cites this verse in a political context -- kill those committing treason, but not their sons, even though they might be the most likely to start a new insurrection.)  God has different rules -- in fact, the Ten Commandments talk about God remembering the sins of fathers against sons. How that works for God ... is a different question. But the answer to your question is simpler -- human justice has stricter controls on it.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Deuteronomy.24.16.2?lang=bi